# React Query with hooks is throwing error, "Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I am working on a React JS project that is using React query, https://react-query.tanstack.com/, React hooks and functional components. But it is throwing error when I use react query for API call.

This is my component and how I use query within it.

```
const App = () => {
   const [ list, updateList ] = useState([])
   const info = useQuery(["item-list"], getList, {
    retry: false,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
  })

  if (info.status == "success") {
     updateList(info.data)
  }
    return (
       //view components here
    )
}
```

This is my getList API call logic

```
export const getList= async () => {
  const { data } = await api.get("8143487a-3f2a-43ba-b9d4-63004c4e43ea");
  return data;
}
```

When I run my code, I get the following error:

> react-dom.development.js:14815 Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main reason of that error here is you are running that code block in the `if` statement in an infinite loop once you have `info.status === 'success'` as `true`. Then in **every render** the `updateList` is called which triggers an another render.

Probably I would use `useEffect` hook here in order to listen for changes at `info` as:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (info.status == "success") {
     updateList(info.data)
  }
}, [info])
```

You should remove that `if` statement from the body of `<App />` component and use the `useEffect` hook instead as suggested above. By doing this that `if` statement will be checked once `info` is changing and not on every render.

Suggested read is [Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Comment: This is the perfect solution. Thanks